# Does Ansible do fault-tolerant SSHing?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible

**Problem Statement:**

I use Ansible for spawning slave instances, and SSHing into them, do some tasks and terminate them.

Suppose the playbook is spawning 3 instances. While SSHing into the slave instances, if one's SSH fails, then do Ansible go ahead with the ones which had a successful SSH, or does it fail the task altogether?

If not, then is there any way I can do it?

PS: I did explore the `ssh_connection`'s `retries` option.  But here, by `failed SSH`, I mean to imply an SSH which failed after retries.

Comment: "*If not, then is there any way I can do it?*" -- do what? The preceding question is "A or B".

Comment: `it` == "Go ahead with the instances with successful SSH, without failing the subsequent tasks below" :) .  Will update the qn properly

Comment: That's what Ansible does by default. Just unplug one server for a moment, or change its IP in the inventory file to check. Doesn't look like a great SO question to me...

Comment: @techraf Will check :) . Sorry, I'm new to Ansible. So, didn't know Ansible already does it.  Possible to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Ansible will run your playbook for all specified hosts. If any of them fails, it will still continue running the playbook for the rest of the hosts, and in the end will create a `playbook.retry` file with the names of the failed hosts, which you can then re-run using:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --limit @playbook.retry
```

(assuming your playbook's name is `playbook.yml`) Note that the re-run will re-run the whole playbook from start, even if some of your tasks have been succeeded in it, hence you should always try to make playbooks resilient to re-runs. Also note that even if you have multiple plays in your playbook, all referring to the same host, the first time the host fails, ansible will not try that host for subsequent plays at all.

There are some ways to change the default behaviour however:

- You can for example [abort the play](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html#aborting-the-play) for some tasks using `any_errors_fatal: true` meaning a failure there will mean ansible will stop execution on all hosts (this assumes you are using the default, [linear strategy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_strategies.html). Using the `free` strategy means that other hosts might be in a different stage, meaning they might abort earlier / later than you'd expect)
- Also, since ansible 2.2 you can [re-set unreachable hosts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html#resetting-unreachable-hosts) between plays, meaning that even if your host failed in one of the plays, in a subsequent ones ansible will still re-try to run the new plays on it (previous plays will still be marked as failed). You have to add `meta: clear_host_errors` to the play where you want to re-try all of the previously unreachable hosts.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer :)